# How can I sort arrays of time/date from oldest to newest in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I have an `array` of dates/times. ("8/28/15, 2:38 PM") I'm trying to order it from newest to oldest date/time. What's the easiest most efficient way?

I was thinking of doing a `for in` loop and have an `if statement` checking if it goes before or after the item before the current one. But I'm sure there is better and more efficient way.

How can I sort arrays of time/date from oldest to newest? (If you need code I have, I can post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array` has a built-in method `sort` which allows you to provide a closure to sort the objects in it. Assuming your variable is called `dates`, you can sort the `NSDate`s inside it like this:

```
dates.sort { (a, b) -> Bool in
    a.earlierDate(b) == a
}
```

The `sort` method repeatedly asks you to compare two dates, asking for which one you want ordered first. You do this by using `NSDate`'s `earlierDate` method to find the date which comes first.

Note: If your array is actually composed of strings of dates rather than `NSDate`s, I'd recommend you convert them to `NSDate`s first.

Comment: Thanks! The way I added the dates to the `array` is like so: date.insert("\(formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))", atIndex: 0) I think that's a `string`. how can I add that as a NSDate? If that's not possible, how can I convert it?

Comment: To insert an `NSDate` into an array, you need to correctly tell your array that it holds `NSDate`s, for example: `var dates = [NSDate]()`. When inserting the date into the array, just use: `dates.append(NSDate())` (you don't need to use `insert:atIndex:` if you're going to sort the array later; `append` just adds it to the end of the array). Later, you can use `formatter.stringFromDate` on them when you're ready to display them to the user, or you need them as a string for some other reason.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this method

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
    sortedArray = [unsorted_array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDate a, NSDate b) {
        return [a compare:b];
    }];
```

Comment: you can try 
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = /*find out and place date format from http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime*/

let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(/*your_date_string*/)